# Scrollable div that takes up remaining height of page

Tags: html, css

I'm essentially trying to create a frame in my page.  Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sa6cb/284/).

```css
html,body{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
}
#container{
 width:100%;
 height:100%;
    position: fixed;
}
#navigation{
 min-height:100%;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
ul {
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>
<div id="container">
    <div id="navigation">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Link</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I would like the `Hello` block to remain at the top and the div with a red background to:

1. Take up the entire rest of the height.
2. Be scrollable if the content overflows.

My attempts to do this have been unsuccessful even after finding a number of similar topics (most of which suggested making the inner content have a `min-height: 100%;`.

I'm attempting to create a container with `position: fixed; height: 100%;` and putting my scrollable area within with `min-height: 100%; overflow-y: auto;`.  Again, this isn't working.

Browser support: IE9+

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the height of the header is **fixed**, you can use CSS [**`calc()`**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) with support for IE9+. Let's say the header is `height: 20px;` then the content would be `height: calc(100% - 20px);` + `overflow-y: auto;` for scrollable overflow.

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqa9kvjh/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}
#header {
    background: lime;
    height: 20px;
}
#content {
    background: teal;
    height: calc(100% - 20px);
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">header</div>
<div id="content">bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla bla</div>
```

Comment: This works great in jsfiddle with static content as well as in Firebug, but when I add it to my Angular app and the content is loaded asynchronously after the page is loaded, the css for `content` becomes `height: calc(-25%);`.  Why would this be?

Comment: What happened to that `100% - 20px`? possibility to do with Angular? I have no idea.

Comment: Escaping LESS FTW! stackoverflow.com/questions/16296521/the-calc-routine-using-less#answer-16296582

Comment: I actually ran into an issue based on how my "frames" are setup.  See my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g3zom8o5/.  I can't set the width of `#container` to 100% because it will run off the screen and when I don't it doesn't take up the whole screen width.

Comment: Does this work? http://jsfiddle.net/g3zom8o5/2/ but looks like you can do a real table layout if you don't care about mobile style.

Comment: Awesome.  Thanks for welcoming me into the world of `calc()`.  It works well so I'll forgo converting to table layout.

Answer (score 3):

### CSS3 and `flex`

```css
* {margin: 0;}
html,body {height: 100%;}

body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}

#container {
  overflow-y: auto;
  flex: 1;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello</h1>

<div id="container">
   <p style="height:2000px;">TALL DEMO</p>END
</div>
```

### CSS and `display table / row`

```css
* { margin: 0;}
html,body {height: 100%;}
body {overflow: hidden;} /* Fix appearing scrollbar in FF*/

.table {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

#row2 {
  height: 100%; /* occupy max height available */
}

.scrollable {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background: gold;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">

  <div class="row" id="row1">
    <h1>Hello</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="row2">
    <div class="scrollable">
      <p style="height:2000px;">TALL DEMO</p>END
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately (and I guess I should have mentioned it in my post), but the app needs to support IE9 so a CSS3 solution is out of the question.

Comment: @im1dermike will the *top Hello* be always the same height? Or does it resizes (logically loosing-gaining height) ?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan the CSS table layout is buggy on Firefox, header won't be fixed at the top of the page when scrolling.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan it's almost the same approach like I did with my previous answer, but it's still buggy, see this http://jsfiddle.net/jdradw3m/ note, it won't display the very bottom of the text in the content area when scroll to the bottom. I would like to know if it's possible to fix too.

Comment: I found a fix @RokoC.Buljan looks like we do need a complete table layout with table-cell too, see this updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2e7cqkty/

Comment: @Pangloss looks like we don't, just a RELATIVE positioned wrapper that will hold the ABSOLUTE scrollable. http://jsbin.com/pofinubuxi/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Yep that did the job too @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways of doing this. One quick a simple way would be:

Give your `h1` a fixed height say `32px`. (better still wrap it and give the wrapper a fixed height). Then height of your container would be `calc(100% - 32px)`. Along with an `overflow: hidden` on your `html,body` and `overflow: auto` on your container.

Here is your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/Sa6cb/285/

Another way could be to use `flex` as demonstrated by @Roko.

Comment: Thanks!  Is the fact that half of the scroll bar is off the screen a product of jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Try [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/1u6rrshj/). Create a header div inside container. Now you have two areas inside it. Give each a max-height in percents. For `#navigation` `overflow:auto`, and you're done.